# Pip install unbearably slow

Tags: pip

Since a few days whenever I run pip install it takes me more than 10 minutes before the package is installed. I already have a `pip.conf` with `extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/`
in it so I do not think pypi being slow is the issue and my network connection is fast.

A test eample:

```
./test/bin/pip install pip --upgrade
```

> Collecting pip
>   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pip
>   Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1 
>   Uninstalling pip-9.0.1: Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
>   Successfully installed pip-20.0.2

How could I fix this problem? I also get

> Cache deserialization failed, entry ignored

every time, which wasn't the case before (that can be fixed with `--no-cache-dir` but I still do not understand what it means). I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Something sounds broken. Can you give an example, eg `python -m venv test-env` then `./test-env/bin/pip install pip --upgrade` and give the output?

Comment: Sure. The output looks fine to me, just the time it takes is very long:            `./test/bin/pip install pip --upgrade  Collecting pip Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  Installing collected packages: pip  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1  Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:  Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1  Successfully installed pip-20.0.2`

Comment: Which point takes a long time? Also, I wonder if you could just delete/clear your cache might help.

Comment: Right after I run `./test/bin/pip install pip --upgrade`...it takes minutes before I see `Collecting pip...`. You mean removing everything in `~/.cache/pip`?

Comment: Did you ever use `sudo pip install ...`? If not, then I assume you haven't broken your system python and the error must be something local, so the cache would be one place to look. If you don't want to delete it, possibly rename it. eg. `mv .cache/pip .cache/pip-broken`.

Comment: Another step, that you have left out, which could help debug: How did you create the virtual environment test. eg. `python3 -m venv test-env` and what was the output from that?

Comment: Deleting the cache did the trick :) Thanks a lot!